# GeoJSON layers with Leaflet in IE8

Tags: leaflet, geojson, internet-explorer

I have built a web site displaying a lot of line shapes, using GeoJSON, on a Leaflet map. This is working relatively well in most browsers, though speed could be improved. As usual IE8 is being the thorn in my side, originally it was not known that IE8 would be a requirement of this project.

I currently cannot get the GeoJSON lines to display on [my large searchable map](http://www.upnorthtrails.org/find-your-trail.html). The lines should display after a couple zooms. Leaflet is not throwing an error, the lines just aren't visible. Has anyone else experienced such an issue, or have an alternative to GeoJSON layers for IE8?

My current set-up is a MySQL database with spatial data from a shapefile, which is then converted into GeoJSON, for Leaflet to render.

Comment: First of all, nice map! I see what you mean on IE 8. I also noticed I cannot pan on the map once zoomed in. I think IE in general is just a pain even when it comes to HTML5 and CSS. Failing a work around, could you create a landing page that recommends Chrome or Firefox instead of IE?

Comment: Thanks, I wish a landing page would do it, that was my plan but the Michigan DNR is the reason for the needed fix, they are limited to IE8.

Comment: You could use WMSand serve queryable images, it would improve the speed and work in all browsers